# Wamp Server : Access from different server possible to phpmyadmin, but not to the sites

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have Wamp Server installed on a Windows Server 2008. It's working fine on local, and here is my phpmyadmin.conf :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

The problem, is that I can access to phpmyadmin from my computer with `servername/phpmyadmin`, but I can't access to my websites nor the index page with `servername/` or `servername/site`.

The port is 80.

I have this error :

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /glpi on this server.

Comment: I precise that none of the solution worked. The questions present in stackoverflow are all about accessing phpmyadmin in local or distant. But there is no case where phpmyadmin is accessible, but not the websites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who this was not obvious, the error came from the first line :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
```

This only give access to the phpmyadmin directory. So the solution is to replace or add a new block with :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
```

And now you'll gain the access to your websites from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to allow access to your site in `\wamp\www\glpi` then the best solution is to create a Virtual Host but if you just want a quick solution all you need to do is use the wampmanager menu as follows :-

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will make the correct change, which is to change the httpd.conf file.

Here is a link to another answer on how and why to create Virtual Hosts, it is aimed at WAMPServer 2.5 but it will work just as well for WAMPServer 2.4 [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)